# Object of type User is not JSON serialiable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a sign up method for users. This is what the user model looks like:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  is_admin = models.BooleanField(blank=True,default=False, verbose_name="Is admin")
  designation = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=True)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=160, blank=False, unique=True)
  password = models.TextField(blank=False)

  USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name + " " + self.email
```

This is what the serializer looks like:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ["id", "name", "designation", "is_admin", "email", "password"]
    extra_kwargs = {
      'password': {'write_only': True}
    }
  
  #creates user after hashing
  #and salting password
  def create(self, validated_data):
    user = User.objects.create(
      name=validated_data.get('name'),
      email=validated_data.get('email'),
      password=make_password(password=validated_data.get('password'), salt=get_random_string(length=32))
    )
    return user
```

The view

```
class AuthViewset(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def signUp(self, request, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        
        is_new = True
        user = User.objects.filter(email=request.data['email']).first()

        if user is not None:
            #user exists
            is_new = False
        else:
            #create user
            user = serializer.create(serializer.validated_data)

        if is_new:
          return Response({
              "user": user,
              "message": "Created new user"
          }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response({
            "message": "User already exists"
        }, status=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT)
```

I've overridden the create method to allow for salting of a hashed password. I want my view method to get the created user, so I return the user object from the create method. But it throws an error saying

```
Object of type User is not JSON serialiable
```

I'm new to django, so I having a tough time understanding why this is happening. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post the full trace of error please ? :)

Comment: json only knows how to represent basic data types: strings, integers, floats, lists, dictionaries, etc.  It doesn't know how to handle custom classes like User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things that you can improve in your code, in general. But, directly to solve your issue. [ViewSet](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions) has no action called `signUp`, change it to `create`, although the main problem is related to the **data you are returning**.

You are returning a model instance, because:

```
user = serializer.create(serializer.validated_data)
```

Instead what you want is to return the serialized data, that can be accessed with `serializer.data`.

```
def create(self, request, **kwargs):
    ...

    # You are returning a model instance, just send the serializer.data
    if is_new:
        return Response({
            "user": serializer.data,
            "message": "Created new user"
        }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        ...
```

Regarding improvements, take a look at this [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example). Your model has no `manager` which would help in hashing the password and using the `management` command `createsuperuser`. The way it is, there is no way to use the admin page, which is a strong feature of the framework.

Lastly, you could get rid of `password` field, you are just overriding `AbstractBaseUser` password. And, rename `AuthViewset` since its not an authentication but a registration endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

This is because a model instance cannot be serialized directly when you try to return `Response({"user": user...` it cannot be completed because python doesn't know how to convert `user` to JSON, to solve that, we can serialize it manually with something like:

```py
return Response({
    "user": { 'name': user.name, 'email': user.email },
    "message": "Created new user"
}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Or even better, use the **Serializer**. With your permission, I would like to suggest some changes to the view implementation:

```py
class AuthViewset(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def signUp(self, request, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        if User.objects.filter(email=serializer.validated_data['email']).exits():
            return Response({
                "message": "User already exists"
            }, status=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT)

        serializer.save()
        
        return Response({
            "user": serializer.data,
            "message": "Created new user"
        }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Always try to avoid the if-else nightmare.